# IOS Core Data Error

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, core-data

I made a testing project of storing a Mutable Array to sqlite data base, but it shows an **error** on save method.

> which is  unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e688c0
>   where the address saved a Catalog object

```
#import "testViewController.h"


@end

@implementation testViewController

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CatalogsList"       inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray* foundObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if([foundObjects count]>0){
        self.l = [foundObjects objectAtIndex:0];

        NSLog(@"found:size of list is %d",[self.l.list count]);

    }else{
        self.l = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CatelogsList" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        self.l.list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:20];
        NSLog(@"not found:size of list:%d",[self.l.list count]);

        //[self.managedObjectContext save:nil];

    }

    self.textField.delegate=self;
    self.catelogText.delegate=self;

}



  - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
 {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
   // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }

-(IBAction)addCatalog
{
    NSString* next name = self.catalogText.text;
    Catalog* newCatelog = [[Catelog alloc] init];
    newCatalog.name = nextname;
   // newCatalog.texts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:20];
    [self.l.list addObject:newCatalog];
    current = newCatalog;

    NSError* error;
    NSLog(@"saving");

    if(![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]){
        NSLog(@"core data failure:%@",error);
        abort();

    }


    NSLog(@"saved size of list is %d",[self.l.list count]);
 }



-(IBAction)show{
    NSLog(@"showing");
    if(self.l.list!=nil){

       for(Catalog* c in self.l.list){
        NSLog(@"Catalog:%@",c.name);        
        }

      }
   }

@end
```

**CataLogsList.h file:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface CatalogsList : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* list;

@end
```

**CataLogsList.m file:**

```
  #import "CatalogsList.h"


@implementation CatalogsList
@dynamic list;

@end
```

**Catalog.h file:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Catelog : NSObject
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString* name;
@end



enter code here
```

Comment: Have you set an Exception breakpoint to see to line of code that's causing this?

Comment: How is the list field described in the Core Data model? It should be of property type Binary Data.

Comment: ...or at least post the what the name of the unrecognized selector is.

Comment: the line causing this is "[self.managedObjectContext save:&error]" in the addCatalog method

Comment: and the list field is described as a transformable in the data model

Comment: Actually,I did saving the NSMutableArray type in this way before and it's working fine. But I got a lot of problems when implement this again in the exactly same way and I can't tell the difference between this and the previous one.

Comment: It has been solved, the point is if you want to store a self-defined class into the sqlite data base,you have to define the two methods for the custom class which are: (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder)coder; and -(id)decodeWithCoder:(NSCoder*)decoder;


thank you guys